# What is the simplest possible package I could make and run?

Tags: python, package

I am struggling a bit to get a package to work, so I would like to just get the simplest possible test case to work.

Here is my current attempt.

Inside of a folder called `Python_experiment` I have two files: a jupyter notebook with the code

```
from .pleasejustwork import eat_muffin
```

and a file called `pleasejustwork.py` with the code

```
def eat_muffin():
     print('i ate a muffin')
```

When I run the line from the jupyter notebook I get the error "attempted relative import with no known parent package". What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you have the `.` in `from .pleasejustwork import eat_muffin`?

Comment: You can't use relative imports from the main script (with which you start your program). A module which does a relative import must be in a package itself.

Comment: "You can't use relative imports from the main script" That was the key piece of information I was missing. Thank you Michael and Grismar. I took out the `.` and it worked. Yes!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you’re using is for a python **package**. To achieve this, place a file, `__init__.py` in the directory. It can be empty. If you’d like to use that package from anywhere, write a `setup.py` script to build and install your package. There are a lot of good tutorials on how do that, like [in the python docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). Then you could do

`from python_experiment.pleasejustwork import eatmuffin` or from another file in the package `from .pleasejustwork import eatmuffin`

If you’re just trying to learn about modules, you can simply take out that leading period

`from pleasejustwork import eatmuffin`

Comment: Taking out the leading period worked like a charm.Thank you! I would like to go one step further and make this work as a package but with a notebook local to this directory so I don't yet have to make setup.py. I have added an empty `__init__.py` file, but I get the same error as before. Just to reiterate, now I have `__init__.py` `pleasejustwork.py` and the jupyter notebook **with the leading period** all in the same directory